# Find the extrema of the implicit function $f(x,y,z(x,y)) = x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> Find the extrema of the implicit function $f(x,y,z(x,y)) = x^2 + y^2 -
>  z^2$

Of course, I start with calculating the partial derivatives by implicit differentiation.
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac x z$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac y z$$
Which yields that the only feasible stationary point is $(0,0)$. 
By the general formula of the function, $z = 0 $. 
But now we have a problem. Since $z = 0$, no partial derivatives at this point exist. 
We could try to check if $(0,0,0)$ is an extremum straight from the definition, but we don't have the formula for $z$. 
I need to find the extremum of $z$.
How do I proceed form here?

Comment: I mean, I don't think that the fact that it is an implicit function changes anything. You can treat the problem like usual. And how do you know that $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac x z$$

Comment: @MarineGalantin, I need to find the extremum of $z$, not $f$.

Comment: ok I see. And so you are working on the surface $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0$ aren't you ? According to the title

Comment: Yes. But as for using Lagrange multipliers, this problem appears in the chapter before them.

Comment: Hi Aemilius, I was watching my previous answers. Is the question answered ? If yes, considere clicking the green arrow :) thanks !

Comment: @MarineGalantin
But of course:D
Sorry that it took so long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that :
$$ x^2 + y^2 = z^2 $$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac x z$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac y z$$

We have that :

$$ \nabla z = ( \frac {x}{ \sqrt{x^2 + y2}} , \frac {y}{ \sqrt{x^2 + y2}}) $$

So apart from $0$, $\nabla z \neq 0$.  Thus, on $\mathbb R^*$, there is no critical point.

Moreover, You have that

- $ O := (0,0,0) $,
- $ E := \{ x,y,z \,| x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \} $,

$$  O \in E  $$

Finally, if we take a look at a point $$ A = (\epsilon,\epsilon,\sqrt 2  \epsilon) $$ for a given, small $\epsilon$, we find that $$ A \in E$$
and $A_z = \sqrt 2 \epsilon > 0$.

We have proven that the origin is a minimum of the function, since you can get as close as you wish from $0$ and you will always be higher than the origin: $A_z > 0$.

So yes, your function is $ \mathcal C^1( \mathbb R^2 / \{(0,0)\})$ thus you can't derivate at $0$, but you can still proove it is a maximum, because the function is continuons on $\mathbb R^2$.